# Pandas: Truth Value of a Series is Ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df`, containing a column called `_type` and one called `avg_engaged_time`.  I want to look at the rows where `_type` is `0` and `avg_engaged_time` is between the 5th and 95th percentile.  Here's my attempt so far:

First I filter based on `_type`:

```
original = result_df[result_df['_type'] == 0.0]
```

Then I find the percentiles:

```
low_original = original['_avg_engaged_time'].quantile(0.05)
high_original = original['_avg_engaged_time'].quantile(0.95)
```

Then I try to filter based on these percentiles:

```
original[original['_avg_engaged_time'] > low_original and original['_avg_engaged_time'] < high_original]
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I just want to use basic Boolean indexing to filter out rows that have an `_avg_engaged_time` less than the 5th percentile or greater than the 95th percentile...

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use bitwise operator `&` instead of `and`. You are doing a logic operation between a list of boolean values, not on single ones.

so

```
original[(original['_avg_engaged_time'] > low_original) & (original['_avg_engaged_time'] < high_original)]
```

should work.

Comment: Hmm, I do that and get `TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

Comment: Probably just a wrong parenthesis from my side. Try again